# Does Twitter have a limit on posts from applications?

Tags: twitter, raspberry-pi2, twython

I'm trying to make a twitterbot that takes and posts pictures. I just ran my program, and it worked, but didn't when I ran it again. I tried a couple more times, stepped away from the computer for a few minutes, and when I came back it worked! But now, it's not posting again. I have not edited the code at all. I have some lines I want to remove because I don't think I need them, but I can't test that when the program seemly runs fine with or without them (no error codes in the shell) but posts nothing either way.
Here's what I've got:

```
#imports
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import os
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *
from twython import Twython
twitter = Twython()

#timestamping
timestamp = datetime.now().isoformat() #creates timestamp
photo_path = '/home/pi/KittyTweeting/Photos/%s.jpg' % (timestamp) #creates filename for photo

#Camera

camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview() #shows picture preview on-screen when running on PC
sleep(1)
camera.capture(photo_path) #takes and saves photo
camera.stop_preview() #ends preview

#Tweeting

tweetStr = "Help" #sets string to be tweeted with image

apiKey = 'removed for posting'

apiSecret = 'removed for posting'

accessToken = 'Removed for posting'

accessTokenSecret = 'Removed for posting'

api = Twython(apiKey,apiSecret,accessToken,accessTokenSecret) #allows communication with Twitter

photo = open(photo_path, 'rb')

api.upload_media(media=photo, status=tweetStr) #posts tweet

#print "Tweeted: " + tweetStr
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Or does Twitter just have some kind of image posting rule that's stopping me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Twitter API is [rate limited](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting):

The response to each API call will contain the following data about the rate limit for that particular API endpoint:

> - `X-Rate-Limit-Limit`: the rate limit ceiling for that given endpoint
> - `X-Rate-Limit-Remaining`: the number of requests left for the 15 minute window
> - `X-Rate-Limit-Reset`: the remaining window before the rate limit resets, in UTC epoch seconds